# Xna Camera placing

Tags: 3d, xna

Hi,

Im trying to do a 3D viewer into Xna GameStudio.

At this moment i know how to move the camera Vector position and the CameraView vector position, but my problem is about rotation (how to move the camera when i use the mouse). 
Like on 3d shooter games.

Any idea, Url or code with some help?

Thanks a lot.
Kind Regards.
Josema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Mouse_camera.php
But any tutorial on mouse movement detection will give you a good start.